How to resolve issue with UpdateReadyMemo output using Inno Setup with Inno Dependency Installer Setup?
How exactly do these <event> functions work in the [Code] section
of Inno Setup?
I see similar question here with no accepted answer:
Inno Setup having multiple UpdateReadyMemo events
I ask because I have an issue that I need to address. I am using the Inno Dependency Installer Setup tool and it includes the following [<event('UpdateReadyMemo')>][2] handler:
<event('UpdateReadyMemo')>
function Dependency_Internal3(const Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + Newline + NewLine;
  end;
  if MemoDirInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + Newline + NewLine;
  end;
  if MemoTypeInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoTypeInfo + Newline + NewLine;
  end;
  if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + Newline + NewLine;
  end;
  if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + Newline + NewLine;
  end;
  if MemoTasksInfo <> '' then begin
    Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo;
  end;

  if Dependency_Memo <> '' then begin
    if MemoTasksInfo = '' then begin
      Result := Result + SetupMessage(msgReadyMemoTasks);
    end;
    Result := Result + FmtMessage(Dependency_Memo, [Space]);
  end;
end;

But, I also have a UpdateReadyMemo handler in my script:
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
    Result := '';
    if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoDirInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if (MemoTasksInfo <> '') then
        Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

    { Only display the Auto Backup Settings info if it is a new install }
    if (not bIsUpgrading) then
        Result := Result + AutoBackupPage_MemoInfo(Space, NewLine);

    Log('UpdateReadyMemo FileToDownload: ' + FilesToDownload);
    if ((FilesToDownload <> '') or WizardIsComponentSelected('downloadhelp')) then
    begin
        Result := Result + ExpandConstant('{cm:ReadyMemo_Download}') + NewLine;

        if (FilesToDownload <> '') then
            Result := Result + FilesToDownload;
    end;
  
end;

It had this bit:
Log('UpdateReadyMemo FileToDownload: ' + FilesToDownload);
if ((FilesToDownload <> '') or WizardIsComponentSelected('downloadhelp')) then
begin
    Result := Result + ExpandConstant('{cm:ReadyMemo_Download}') + NewLine;

    if (FilesToDownload <> '') then
        Result := Result + FilesToDownload;
end;

When I run my installer:

What I would like to see here is:
Download files:
    MSAHelpDocumentationSetup.exe
    .NET Runtime 8.0.3 (x64)

How can I achieve this result?
